# CPU usage per Thread on Jolokia?

Tags: java, analytics, jolokia

We are facing a very problematic issue in our production environment. Our users somehow dispatch a specific action that overload our server instace CPU.

In order to look at what is happening, I have deployed Jolokia along with my JSF application on a Tomcat 7 server running on a kubernetes cluster.

I am not very experienced on monitoring java applications, but I believe the metric I am looking for is a **CPU usage vs Thread**, but I can't find how to extract this metric from our instance using Jolokia rest api.

So I want to know how I can do it, and also, if someone has a clue of a better metric for us to use, that would also be welcome.

Comment: Can you recomend me one that I can use on a remote instance?

Comment: wow! mind blowing!

Comment: I am not asking you to do so, I am asking supposing you have previous experience on the matter since, as I stated, Its my first time doing that. But if you don't know, then just don't reply rather than pasting a google url. That is rude bro. Cheers

Comment: Well, given the alternatives provided that's pretty much the best one, thank you